# How to fit placeholder font-size for input[type=text] to see it totaly?

Tags: css, font-size, placeholder

I have an HTML `input[type='text']` with a placeholder. The input size is already determined by its container.

I would like to find a way to fit the placeholder size with the input width and add a minimum size.

```
<div id="container" style="width: 50px">
    <input type='text' width='100%' placeholder='A placeholder which should be seen totaly'/>
</div>
```

I tried :

```
input::placeholder {
    font-size: Xvw; //<-- I don't find how it works in this case
    font-size: 100%; //<-- Does not work
}
```

Someone has an idea ?

Comment: means you want to control your placeholder font-size according to the width of input?

Comment: Yes exactly, but with a minimum size if the browser window is too small.

Comment: only using javascript to determine the width and set a css class on the container